# Ambiguity tree: The doctor visited the patient drunk

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, ambiguity

I would like to ask if the trees regarding the two different readings of the sentence "The doctor visited the patient drunk" were drawn correctly.

a) [VP [^NP The doctor] [V' [V visited] [NP [D the] [N'[N patient] [AdjP[Adj'[Adj drunk]]]

The patient drunk, was visited by the doctor.

b) [VP [^NP The doctor] [VP [V' [V visited] [^NP the patient]] [AdvP drunk]]]

The doctor, drunk, visited the patient.

I understand that "ambiguity" is understood by the fact that "drunk" in one sentence is an adjunct and in the other sentence is not, but I don't know if it drawn correctly to show that.

Thanks :)

Comment: a) is missing at least one right bracket ] at the end.